# Awk script for my data

Tags: awk

I have a file which has these columns:

```
chr1    1397031 1445511   360   chr1    1436533 1436893
chr1    3558988 3639716   9837  chr1    3565359 3575196
chr1    9634389 9711556   1958  chr1    9635273 9637231
chr1    10657207 10657742  535  chr1    10629864 10676549
chr1    12590100 12594553 4453  chr1    12550526 12600407
chr1    14599424 14601321 1897  chr1    14590538 14619056
chr1    15352815 15419459 7429  chr1    15363278 15370707
```

The fourth column represents the overlap between the 2nd, 3rd, 6th and the 7th columns.

So,the smaller one between the 7th column and the 3rd is the end position of the overlapping region. And the bigger one between the 2nd column and the 6th is the start position.

Can anyone help with an `awk` script ?

Comment: What do you want to do with this data? Do you want to extract some information or transform the data?

Comment: What have you tried?  It looks like a straight-forward job since `awk` splits the input into the 7 fields for you.  Of course, it will also help to understand what you're trying to.  Are you verifying that the fourth column is correct?  Or recalculating it?  Or printing the bounds of the overlap in new columns 8 and 9?

Answer (score 1):

well your question is not that clear.. you described your data, but didn't mention what do you want to get..

I **guess** you want to list the start/end of your "overlapping" right?

```
awk '{s=$2>=$6?$2:$6;e=$3<=$7?$3:$7;print $1,s,e,$4}' file
```

the output would be:

```
chr1 1436533 1436893 360
chr1 3565359 3575196 9837
chr1 9635273 9637231 1958
chr1 10657207 10657742 535
chr1 12590100 12594553 4453
chr1 14599424 14601321 1897
chr1 15363278 15370707 7429
```

columns:

```
col1 is the text
col2 is the overlapping start
col3 is the overlapping end
col4 is the overlap
```

a magic answer to magic question...:)

Comment: A little conflicted about upvoting this one, IHMO you're enabling doofus behavior on the part of newbie posters ("q not that clear" would be an polite understatement ;-) ... But very nice to see ternary operators being used in a one-liner. So +1. Good luck to all.